# javascript variable manipulation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)
>   [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

when i run following code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var  a=0.1;
var b=0.2;
var c=0.3;
document.write((a+b)+c);
document.write(' ');
document.write(a+(b+c));
document.write('  ');
document.write(a+b);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

it shows me follwoing  result

```
0.6000000000000001 0.6 0.30000000000000004
```

i dont understand how `a+b=0.30000000000000004` also  0.30000000000000004+0.3 how is equal to 0.6?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: [This article](http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html) will answer your question in depth